# Set ionice for a multi-threaded application

Tags: linux, process, io, multithreading, ionice

I have a program that spawns multiple threads, all of which do fairly intensive IO, running on the background. I want to set the scheduling class to `idle` so that it doesn't clog up the system; however, `ionice -c3 -p <PID>`, where `<PID>` is the process ID, does not have the desired effect. Although the scheduling class for process `<PID>` is changed, when I launched `iotop`, all the threads it had spawned still had the default priority (best-effort level 4).

How do I change the IO priority of a program and all the threads or processes it has spawned on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionice` can take a process group ID as an argument (`-P` switch), which, obviously, affects all processes (and threads) in the given process group. Once can find the process group ID by looking at the 5th field of `/proc/<PID>/stat` (or using `ps`). This setting is a bit more coarse than what I really wanted, but works well enough.